# How to click 5 star in Google ratings with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write a review for a place on google maps and give it 5 stars. I've done the comment part, but I can't click on the stars.

the part of code i wrote to send comment and give 5 stars:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[18]/iframe")))

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/textarea")).send_keys("Comment")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div > div > div > div.O51MUd > div.l5dc7b > div.DTDhxc.eqAW0b > div.euWHWd.aUVumf > div > div:nth-child(5)"))).click()
```

the error message i got:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="s2xyy" role="radio" aria-label="Five star" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0" jsaction="click:uOnRTe; keydown:g6LwHf" data-rating="5">...</div> is not clickable at point (281, 158). Other element would receive the click: <div class="heUEcb">...</div>
```

the place I used as an example:
[empire state building](https://www.google.com/search?q=empire%20state&biw=1920&bih=841&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=AOaemvL7OVsfVFejU7WtvWANxm7YYVsF3g%3A1641130676800&ei=tKrRYfukMJ6Pxc8PpZ-guAU&oq=empire&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39k1j0i67k1j0i433i67k1l2j0i67k1j0i512i433k1j0i512i433i131k1j0i512k1l2j0i67k1.3750.4614.0.5688.6.6.0.0.0.0.148.521.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.4.520...0i433i131i67k1.0.zYRVJP0v614#lrd=0x89c259a9b3117469:0xd134e199a405a163,3,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:15074921902713971043,l,CgxlbXBpcmUgc3RhdGVIn6MFWhoQABABGAAYASIMZW1waXJlIHN0YXRlMgJlbpIBEnRvdXJpc3RfYXR0cmFjdGlvbg;mv:%5B%5B40.7623369,-73.9734876%5D,%5B40.746033499999996,-73.9899202%5D%5D)

I tried all kinds of ways but I couldn't. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there is an overlapping element. Try closing the element or the below.

```
elem=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div > div > div > div.O51MUd > div.l5dc7b > div.DTDhxc.eqAW0b > div.euWHWd.aUVumf > div > div:nth-child(5)")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Comment: dude you are my hero.